# Difference between Bean of Map<String, Object> vs Map<String, String>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean

can someone explain following scenario, it's really appreciated...

I defined two Beans of Map class, one with type Map<String, String> and other one is Map<String, Object>. Check the following code.

```java
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
    public class Application {
    
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> waitingTopicMap() {
            return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Map<String, String> subscribeResponseMap() {
            return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        }
    }
```

these bean will be used in two classes, check the following code...

```java
    @Service
    public class ConsumerServiceImpl implements ConsumerService {
    
        private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
        @Autowired
        private Map<String, Object> waitingTopicMap;
    
        @Autowired
        private Map<String, String> subscribeResponseMap;
    
        @Override
        public void putMessageToSubscribeMap(String subscribeTopic, String message) {
    
            try {
    
                waitingTopicMap.put(subscribeTopic, new Object());
                subscribeResponseMap(subscribeTopic, message);
    
                logger.debug("Response message put into map");
    
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Service
    public class DeviceInteractionServiceImpl implements DeviceInteractionService {
    
        @Autowired
        private PublisherService publisherService;
    
        @Autowired
        private Map<String, Object> waitingTopicMap;
    
        @Autowired
        private Map<String, String> subscribeResponseMap;
    
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> processRequest(Map<String, Object> receivedMap, HttpServletRequest request) {
    
            logger.debug("receivedMap {}", receivedMap);

            // some logic will be going here....
            String topic = waitingTopicMap.get(receivedMap.get("topic));
            String message = subscribeResponseMap.get(topic);
            publisherService.publish(topic, message);
    
        }
    }
```

when I tried to run this code I'm getting cycle dependency error, check the following sample error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   messageBrokerConfigDev defined in file [D:\Projects\DeviceInteractionEngine\build\classes\java\main\die\config\MessageBrokerConfigDev.class]
┌─────┐
|  handlerDev defined in class path resource [die/config/MessageBrokerConfigDev.class]
↑     ↓
|  consumerServiceImpl (field private java.util.Map die.service.impl.ConsumerServiceImpl.waitingTopicMap)
↑     ↓
|  deviceInteractionController (field private die.service.DeviceInteractionService die.controller.DeviceInteractionController.deviceInteractionService)
↑     ↓
|  deviceInteractionServiceImpl (field private java.util.Map die.service.impl.DeviceInteractionServiceImpl.waitingTopicMap)
└─────┘
```

There is some controller name DeviceInteractionController and it has dependency to deviceInteractionServiceImpl class

The problem I can't understand is before I change the code it already having these two Map beans but both are Map<String, String> type. like this...

```java
    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> waitingTopicMap() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> subscribeResponseMap() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }
```

Above code will not provide any error (I can run the project normally).
Spring boot version 1.5.22, jdk 1.8 used in project

what did I missed here? I really appreciate any input to solve this matter..

Comment: So if you changed both back to `Map<String, String>`, it will work ?

Comment: yes. That's right.